# zsh: command not found: heruko - How to get up and running with Heroku CLI on Mac Catalina?

Tags: macos, salesforce, command-line-interface, homebrew, zshrc

With brew I have downloaded and installed Heroku CLI.

But when I open a Terminal and type heruko, I get this response:

```
% heruko
zsh: command not found: heruko'
```

I followed the instructions on devcenter.heroku.com

macOS:

```
$ brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Apperently the install has been succesful, because when I try to run it again I get the message:

```
Warning: heroku/brew/heroku 7.42.4 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 7.42.4, run `brew reinstall heroku`
```

Should some path variable be added to the .zshrc file?
I already have some path variables to other stuff in my .zshrc file, this is how it looks now:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/a/Documents/downloaded-tools/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

**Shall there be added an entry about Heroku CLI, there?
If so, exactly what should be added?**

I am running a Mac Book Pro 2019 16" - Catalina

Comment: you made "heroku / heruko" typo in the actual commands or only in this question?

Comment: You are so right! When I typed it correct everything works. Thank you!